# How can I stop cin.getline() from causing the console to repeatedly get user input when the delimiter is not found?

Tags: c++, input, cin, istream

```
std::istream & Date::read(std::istream & istr)
{
  char* buffer = nullptr;

  const bool ISTREAM_IS_OKAY = !(istr.fail());//okay if it didn't fail
  if (ISTREAM_IS_OKAY)
  {      
      cout << "Enter a string: ";
      const int SIZE = 256;
      buffer = new char[SIZE];
      istr.getline(buffer, SIZE);
      cout << "\n" << buffer << " " << strlen(buffer) << endl;
      istr.getline(buffer, SIZE, '/');
      cout << "\n" << buffer << " " << strlen(buffer) << endl;
      istr.getline(buffer, SIZE, '/');
      cout << "\n" << buffer << " " << strlen(buffer) << endl;


  }
  else
  {//CIN_FAILED is a pre-processor directive which is equal to 1
      m_readErrorCode = CIN_FAILED; //m_readErrorCode is just an int
  }

  delete[] buffer;

return istr;
}
```

I am trying to read in a date in one string using cin.getline(). Dependent upon whether the boolean member variable m_dateOnly is true or false, the date is to be printed in one of the following two fashions:

1) if(m_dateOnly==true)....

2017/3/18

2) else...print the date and time

2017/3/18 , 12:36

I'm aware that the logic in my code does not entirely dictate what I just explained(It's still a WIP). I came to a halt because when I enter the following:

"abcd"       ... no delimiter here

cin.getline() continues to run until the user enters a string with the given delimiter in it.

How can I get cin.getline() to stop on the first instance of an invalid string as opposed to it continuously running?

Note: I am required to use the istream passed as an argument

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to do fancy things like stopping each time the user inputs an invalid character, you will have to use other methods than `getline`. You can, for instance, use the even lower level methods `sgetc`/`sbumpc` and check each character before deciding to add it to a valid input string. This is rather tedious though, because you'll have to handle all the buffer overflow / end of input checks `getline` automatically takes care of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can't, because `getline` will not stop until it encounters the terminator it expects, the buffer gets full or the input ends.

At any rate, you can't pass it a list of 2 characters or more (the expected terminator and/or some illegal characters) it should stop on.

If you really want your code to react on a character per character basis, you will need to use character by character input, with methods like `sgetc` or `sbumpc`.
I would not advise to do so, because that would force you to handle all the pesky edge cases like your input buffer getting full of the input being terminated, which `getline` can handle without headache.

You could also use the `>>` operator to grab bits of characters or numbers according to whatever format is expected for your date and time. Trouble is, that would force you to check the state of your input stream after each >> invokation, making for ponderous and nigh unreadable code.

Another possibility is to use `scanf` like functions, but they have the slight downside of including an undefined behaviour on numeric inputs, meaning typing a large number of digits when it expects a number could theoretically lead to a program crash, a random memory corruption or your mustache turning pink.

Yet another possibility is to piss a couple dozen lines of code to create your own homemade list of separators through the `imbue` method and a custom `ctype` object. I would not touch that with a 10 feet pole, but I'm sure a lot of senior developpers pull that trick to impress the chicks...

Now if you ask me, C++ string I/O is an appallingly awkward leftover from the 90's: no regular expressions, no garbage collection, no associative memory, so you will end up checking the characters you just read, monitoring the state of your I/O stream and allocating bits of buffers every second line of code. You're bound to suffer one way or another. I would just not make it more painful than it has to be, if I were you.

The usual way of circumventing the crappy C++ I/O is to read a plain line (terminated by a good old `\n`, usually what you get when you hit the `enter` key), and then analyze the resulting string buffer by hand. Once you're done with reading an actual input, you don't have to worry about buffers overflowing or input terminating at an awkward moment. That usually makes things a lot less messy.

btw. my personal preference goes to never having to call `delete` on a null pointer. You can do it, but that makes for pretty dangerous code that tends to break if you modify it one time too many. It could arguably save you a few minutes of coding, but might also cost you (or one of your infortunate coworkers) a few hours of debugging a few weeks/months later.

If your buffer is only used within a code block, better make it a local variable that will be cleaned up automatically. Use dynamic allocation only when you really need it.

No doubt a lot of C++ zealots will be eager to explain the contrary, but this bit of wisdom comes from long nights spent munching pizzas in front of buggy code, often written by people who were just a bit too smart for their own good (and the good of their coworkers, incidentally). Make what you want of it, it comes free of charge.